# How can i update a JSON data in Android

Tags: android, json

How can I update a JSON data in Android. I get several data sets and I want to change one. How can I do  this?

Comment: So, What you have try ?

Comment: you question is unclear,please explain more

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you post some of your code so we can see what might be problematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily override the `value` you want, simply putting the same `Object` (key, value pair with the same key and different value) again in the `JSONObject`.

**E.g:-**

```
String jsonStr = "{\"a\" = 1, \"b\" = 2}";
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    json.put("a", 3);
} catch (JSONException e) {}
```

Modify this as per your needs and `JSON` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html#androidjson_write

```
  public void writeJSON() {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
      try {
        object.put("name", "Jack Hack");
        object.put("score", new Integer(200));
        object.put("current", new Double(152.32));
        object.put("nickname", "Hacker");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(object);
    }
```